# How to use different APIs

Tags: python, api, wunderground

I'm trying to create a program that can successfully tell you the weather via using a weather api. 
This is the api I will be using http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/docs

I'm struggling to understand how to use this Api. I'm finding it to be rather confusing. I have tried to use the sample code presented by wunderground however it doesn't seem to be working in my editor(possibility due to code being another version of python.) I'm using python 3.5
Any comments and any suggestions would be greatly appreciated on how I can go about using this api.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample code modified for Python 3:

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
import json

API_KEY = 'your API key'
url = 'http://api.wunderground.com/api/{}/geolookup/conditions/q/IA/Cedar_Rapids.json'.format(API_KEY)

request = Request(url)
response = urlopen(request)
json_string = response.read().decode('utf8')
parsed_json = json.loads(json_string)
location = parsed_json['location']['city']
temp_f = parsed_json['current_observation']['temp_f']
print("Current temperature in %s is: %s" % (location, temp_f))
response.close()
```

Obviously you need to sign up and get an API key. Use that key as the value for `API_KEY`. If you look at the code sample whilst logged in the key will already be inserted into the URL for you.

You could also use the [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) module which is easier to work with, and supports Python 2 and 3:

```
import requests

API_KEY = 'your API key'
url = 'http://api.wunderground.com/api/{}/geolookup/conditions/q/IA/Cedar_Rapids.json'.format(API_KEY)

response = requests.get(url)
parsed_json = response.json()
location = parsed_json['location']['city']
temp_f = parsed_json['current_observation']['temp_f']
print("Current temperature in %s is: %s" % (location, temp_f))
```

Comment: thanks for this sample code however when I put the code in idle   I get this error. 

        location = parsed_json['location']['city']
        KeyError: 'location'

Comment: Why do you think that might be? Try looking at the value of `parsed_json`. You might find that the API key that you used is incorrect. Or perhaps the city that you've requested is invalid. Try `parsed_json['response']['error']`

Comment: Again, look at the value of `parsed_json`? You are now reporting a different error - does `parsed_json['location']['city']` work? Did you sign up and retrieve an API key? This is pretty basic stuff. Perhaps you need to read up on Python dictionaries.

Comment: no  it doesn't work.
parsed_json['location']['city']
and yes I have got a key

Comment: So what _exactly_ is contained in `parsed_json`? Take a look at it and post it here if it is not too long. You probably have an error response.

Comment: this is the problem
 File "C:/Users/Muzz/Documents/Python Project/weatherlocationwithapi.py", line 16, in <module>
    temp_f = parsed_json['current_observation']['temp_f']
KeyError: 'current_observation

Comment: I know that. Final try: what is the value of `parsed_json`? Do not try to access its keys, just display it with `print(parsed_json)`.

Comment: This is what happens 
{'response': {'error': {'description': 'this key does not exist', 'type': 'keynotfound'}, 'features': {}, 'termsofService': 'http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/terms.html', 'version': '0.1'}}

Comment: OK, so you are not using a valid API key. Did you replace the line in the sample script `API_KEY = 'your API key'` with _your_ API key? It should be a 16 byte hex string, e.g.  `API_KEY = 'a17e6a58ed4001a9'`

Comment: yes @mhawke
API_KEY = 'Your key here' - i placed my api key in here

Comment: Then you have used the wrong key. You can try with my key which I created just for testing : `API_KEY = 'f17e6a58ed4001a9'`.

Comment: @mkhawke thanks a lot this works, i dont understand how i've got the wrong key. I signed up and selected the developer version however  the API key that I used was incorrect.  I received my key in the table where it gives the url referral link .